# Substracting time in R

Tags: r

I want to calculate the amount of time someone spends in bed at night.
First column, j1bed (time goes to bed):

```
dput(head(subscales$j1bed, 20))

c("23:00:00", "01:00:00", "22:00:00", "00:00:00", "00:00:00", 
"23:00:00", "03:00:00", "23:00:00", "22:00:00", "23:00:00", "21:00:00", 
"23:30:00", "22:00:00", "22:00:00", "20:00:00", "22:00:00", "22:00:00", 
"21:00:00", "20:00:00", "23:00:00")
```

Second column, j3wake (time wakes up):

```
dput(head(subscales$j3wake, 20))

c("08:00:00", "08:00:00", "05:00:00", "08:00:00", "07:00:00", 
"07:00:00", "09:00:00", "09:00:00", "08:00:00", "06:00:00", "03:00:00", 
"08:30:00", "07:00:00", "08:00:00", "09:00:00", "07:00:00", "06:00:00", 
"07:00:00", "07:00:00", "12:00:00")
```

My code currently is as follows:

```
Hours_in_Bed<- as.numeric(difftime(strptime(subscales$j3wake, "%I:%M %p" ),strptime(subscales$j1bed, "%I:%M %p" ),units='hours'))
```

For some reason, this is coming up with only "NA". Any ideas?

Edit: I've tried the following three suggestions:
1)

```
result1<-strptime(subscales$j3wake, "%I:%M %p")

result2<-strptime(subscales$j1bed, "%I:%M %p")

Hours_in_Bed<-as.numeric(difftime(result2, result1, units='hours'))
```

This yields only "NA"s.
2)

```
 subscales$j3wake1=as.POSIXct(paste('1970-1-1',subscales$j3wake))
subscales$j1bed1 =as.POSIXct(paste('1970-1-1',subscales$j1bed))
as.numeric(difftime(subscales$j1bed1,subscales$j3wake1,units='hours'))
```

This yields "0"s.
3)

```
 all(grepl("[0-9]{2}:[0-9]{2} (AM|PM)", subscales$j3wake)) 

all(grepl("[0-9]{2}:[0-9]{2} (AM|PM)", subscales$j1bed))
```

Both yield "False".

Edit 2: that last tip was key! I think I should be using "%H:%M" instead:

```
Hours_in_Bed<- as.numeric(difftime(strptime(subscales$j3wake, "%H:%M" ),strptime(subscales$j1bed, "%H:%M" ),units='hours'))
```

If I then do:

```
Hours_in_Bed[!is.na(Hours_in_Bed) & Hours_in_Bed<0] <- 24 + Hours_in_Bed[!is.na(Hours_in_Bed) & Hours_in_Bed<0]
```

I should be good to go. Let me know if I'm still off, and thanks for the help!

Comment: It's hard to reproduce the error without reproducible data -- would you mind sharing `dput(head(subscales$j3wake, 20))` and `dput(head(subscales$j1bed, 20))`?

Comment: purple_olive, this was mentioned in your last question: please make this question more *reproducible* by including sample data and expected output. Refs: https://stackoverflow.com/q/5963269, [mcve], and https://stackoverflow.com/tags/r/info.

Comment: `strptime` returns `NA` when the input strings do not match the format you are passing to it. For instance, `strptime("12:03 pm", "%I:%M %p")` works just fine, but `strptime("2020-02-02 12:03 pm", "%I:%M %p")` does not. Look at your `subscales` variables and make sure that `all(grepl("[0-9]{2}:[0-9]{2} (AM|PM)", subscales$j3wake))` (and for `$j1bed`) is true.

Comment: Try separating the parts of the calculation so you can look at the intermediate results. I think you'll find the problem there. E.g. `result1 <- strptime(...)`, `result2 <- striptime(...)`, `result3 <- difftime(...)`, etc.

Answer (score 1):

It's usually easier to use the POSIXct-type even if there isn't any real year/month/day. Example:

```
subscales$j3wake1 = as.POSIXct(paste('1970-1-1',subscales$j3wake))
subscales$j1bed1 = as.POSIXct(paste('1970-1-1',subscales$j1bed))
as.numeric(difftime(subscales$j1bed1,subscales$j3wake1,units='hours'))
```